# Android - Getting more than 2 OnCompleteListener events simultaneously from MediaPlayer

Tags: android, media-player

Hey guys I have come across an issue when using the MediaPlayer class in Android

Before you suggest SoundPool, I need an OnCompletion event to fire when the sound clip is done playing otherwise I would use it.

So the problem is is that when 3 or more clips are activated at the same time I only get the OnCompletion for the last 2 events, not all of them, anyone know a solution to this problem or know why it is happening?

```
// When the user clicks on the Chicken Image, this Function is called
public void onChickenClicked(View view)
{
//  ToastMsg( "You Clicked the Chicken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT );
    // Then play the sound,
    mMediaPlayer[CHICKEN] = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.chicken_sound );
    // Start playing the sound
    mMediaPlayer[CHICKEN].start();
    // This is to catch when the sound clip has ended, this will be 
    //     used to stop the animation for the chicken
    mMediaPlayer[CHICKEN].setOnCompletionListener( new OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            System.err.println("Chicken On Complete");
            // Stop the animation of the Chicken here
            mAnimation.cancel();
            mAnimation.reset();
            // Then switch the image back to the original Chicken pic
            ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewofChicken);
            imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.chicken);
            mMediaPlayer[CHICKEN].reset();
        }} );

    // Finds the ImageView, replaces the base img with the alternate img, and plays the sound
    animatePicture( R.id.imageViewofChicken, R.drawable.chicken_tongue);
}   




public void onCowClicked(View view)
{
//  ToastMsg( "You Clicked the Cow", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT );
    // Then play the sound, 
    mMediaPlayer[COW] = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.cow_sound );
    // Start playing the sound
    mMediaPlayer[COW].start();
    // This is to catch when the sound clip has ended, this will be 
    //     used to stop the animation for the chicken
    mMediaPlayer[COW].setOnCompletionListener( new OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            System.err.println("Cow On Complete");
            // Stop the animation of the Chicken here
            mAnimation.cancel();
            mAnimation.reset();
            // Then switch the image back to the original Chicken pic
            ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewofCow);
            imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.cow);
            mMediaPlayer[COW].reset();
        }} );
    // Finds the ImageView, replaces the base img with the alternate img, and plays the sound
    animatePicture( R.id.imageViewofCow, R.drawable.cow_tongue);
}

//there are more but you get it idea here.
```

Anyone have any ideas on how I can get all of the OnCompleteListeners to fire?

Comment: So I think I figured it out, I simply replace the MediaPlayer with the SoundPool, and then used

    private final ScheduledExecutorService mScheduler =   Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(MAX_ANIMALS);

to handle when the sound clips were done with, based on a function I saw on stackoverflow using the MediaPlayer to load the sound, then get the duration in milliseconds, as the delay for the scheduler.

Comment: private int getSoundClipDuration( int rawSoundId ) {

     // Create a MediaPlayer to play our sound
     MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create( MainActivity.this, rawSoundId );
     if( mp == null ) {
      return -1;
     }
     int duration = mp.getDuration(); // Get the Length of the Sound Clip
     mp.reset();
     mp.release(); // Release the MediaPlayer for others to use
     return duration;
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out, I simply replaced the MediaPlayer with the SoundPool, and then used

`private final ScheduledExecutorService mScheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(MAX_ANIMALS);`

to handle when the sound clips were done with, based on a function I saw on stackoverflow using the MediaPlayer to load the sound, then get the duration in milliseconds, and use it as the delay for the scheduler (`mScheduler[x]`).

It's a hack, but it got it done.